# Octopack retention

Tags: jenkins, octopus-deploy

How do you set retention policy for Octopack in Jenkins? All I can find is retention for Jenkins project itself, and the octopus release itself, as well as the nuget packages in octopus repository, but not the .nupkg-files created by Octopack in the workspace folder of jenkins. They are 200mb each and eating up my hard drive.

I cannot find anything on octopus webpage, nor the jenkins plugin page regarding correct build parameter.

Comment: where are you publishing the packages to?

Comment: The packages are published via octopack to my own setup of Octopus deploy.

Comment: So you are storing the packages in the Octopus private nuget repository

Comment: Yes, they are stored in the octopus private repository, but the nuget files are also stored in the bin-folder for the build, and the retention does not apply to the build folder i presume. My best guess is jenkins builds the package, sends it to octopus, but somehow fails to remove the .nupkg file in the workspace

Comment: In that case, I'd add a build step to delete the packages from the bin folder once the packages have been published to Octopus. Could just be a command prompt script along the lines of `del .\bin\*.nupkg`

Comment: Thanks! Why didn't I think of that. Worked as a charm after som tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use the package retention policy combined with the releases retention policy?
[image: package retention policy]
[image: release retention policy]

That would however only affect packages inside Octopus NuGet repository, not an external NuGet feed.

Comment: No, this on applies to the retention of the packages in octopus repository, and not the .nupkg-files in the build workspace in jenkins

Comment: Ok, I see. My bad.